# How to round to n decimal places a calculated field in Java using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, java-8

How do you round to n decimal places a calculated field using hibernate annotation `@Format`?

```
@Column(name = "weight")
@Formula("round(weight/1000)")
private Double weight;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use Java **Decimalformat** util class. You should use that pattern: ###.##

If you want to round n decimal places then do:

```
String s = ".";
for(int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
    s += "#";
}
if(n <= 0) {
    s = "";
}
System.out.println(new DecimalFormat("###" + s).format(ur number));
```

idk if it's right. If a made any misteak then correct me.

Comment: `DecimalFormat.format` returns a `String`. Question focuses on retrieving a rounded `double` value from db.

Answer (score 0):

You could multiply the number with 10 to the power n, round it off to the nearest whole number and then divide it with 10 to the power n again.

```
@Column(name = "weight")
@Formula("round(weight/1000)")
private Double weight;
n=5;                            //just for demonstration purposes
weight *= Math.pow(10,n);       //multiplying it by 10 to the power n
Math.round(weight);             //rounding it off
weight /= Math.pow(10,n);       //getting the rounded off value for weight
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, when using defining your `@Formula`, you use `1000` instead of `1000.0`. I encountered issues with SQL rounding the answer to an Int value without using `1000.0`.

Secondly, you can add an `n` value when using the postgres [ROUND function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/functions-math.html).

> round(v numeric, s int)

`round(42.4382, 2)`

> 42.44

Solution:

```
@Column(name = "weight")
@Formula("ROUND(weight/1000.0, 2)")
private Double weight;
```

Where in this example `2` is your `n` value.